# Safari 7 doesn't to allow local file access through web page

Tags: macos, safari, osx-mavericks

I have silverlight Web Application which is working fine on all the version of safari except safari 7 on 10.9.
I am not able to access local file system.It is saying file not avaibale.
Is this bug or I need to set any setting to allow local file access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to run the plugin in Unsafe mode for that web site.

Safari->Preference->Manage WebSite Setting->Select "Web Site" right click it and "Run in Unsafe Mode"

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/removing-sandbox-restrictions-your-safari.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have the developer tools menu enabled (Develop) you can select "Disable Local File Restrictions" there.